# Redirect to specific page after session expires (MVC6)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a C# MVC6 project and I want to redirect to a specific page when the session expires.

After some research I tried creating

```
public class SessionExpireAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute

HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
```

but `HttpContext.Current` does not exist in Asp.Net 5.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

If you override one of the ActionFilterAttribute methods, you can access Session easily enough:

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    context.HttpContext.Session...
}
```

Is this sufficient?